# How to handle file upload using sequelize + mysql + express js?

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

I'm developing a simple software college project that needs pdf/doc file upload. But here comes the bottleneck: I couldn't find anywhere an example and example of this feature using the Sequelize ORM.

Has anyone done something similar using this framework?

*By the way, I know there are several npm packages for express(), but I must use sequelize.

Any advice is welcome.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configure your express app with [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer). Read over the documentation for multer, but in short you store the path of the uploaded file:

```
const multer = require('multer')
const express = require('express')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password')

const MyModel = sequelize.define('myModel', {
  filePath: Sequelize.STRING,
})

const express = express()

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, './app/uploads')
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
})

app.post('/upload', multer({ storage }).single('example'), async (req, res) => {
    // This needs to be done elsewhere. For this example we do it here.
    await sequelize.sync()

    const filePath = `${req.file.destination}/${req.file.filename}`
    const myModel = await MyModel.create({ filePath })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler example ([from](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/a509d54d-d354-451f-a0dd-89a2e717c10b/entry/How_to_upload_a_file_using_Node_js_Express_and_Multer?lang=en)) using AJAX.

Add to your node.js

```
var multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
        console.log(req);
        callback(null, './uploads');
    },
    filename: (req, file, callback) => {
        console.log(req);
        callback(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({storage:storage}).single('myFile');

app.post('/dashboard/myFile', function(req,res){
        upload(req,res,function(err){
            //console.log("owen",req.file,err);
            if (err)
                return res.end("error uploading file");
            res.end("file is uploaded");
        });
});
```

And in your HTML

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input id="myFile" name="myFile" type="file">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>


<script>

var form = document.forms.namedItem("myForm");

form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev){
    var myFile = document.getElementById('myFile').files[0];
    var oData = new FormData(form);
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("POST","/uploadFile",true);
    oReq.onload = function(oEvent){
        if(oReq.status == 200) {
            console.log("success",oEvent);
        } else {
            console.log("fail",oEvent);
        }
    }
    oReq.send(oData);
    ev.preventDefault();
},false);

</script>
```